# How to change screen resolution in Xubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, resolution

I can't figure out how to change my screen resolution.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You could go to settings > settings-manager > display and change it there (`xfce4-display-settings` is the actual application used) or use `xrandr -s 1280x1024` or whatever your desired resolution is.

Answer (score 1):

open the settings manager menu, click on "display" and you can change it from there

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings Manager then Display and change it. If unable to then check the Alternitave drivers to see if the display adapter is installed.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my graphical display option was not working. I managed to change the resolution to 1920x1080 using this command:

```
xrandr -s 1280x1024
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top left blue icon, search for "Display". Then, select a resolution from the dropdown and click on "Apply".